# Averaging over specific months in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm having trouble creating averages using pandas. My problem is that I want to create the averages combining the months Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb,March, for each winter, however they fall on different years and therefore I can't just do an average of those values falling within one calendar year. I have tried subsetting the data into two datetime objects as..

```
nd_npi_obs = ndjfm_npi_obs[ndjfm_npi_obs.index.month.isin([11,12])]
jfm_npi_obs = ndjfm_npi_obs[ndjfm_npi_obs.index.month.isin([1,2,3])]
```

..however I'm having trouble manipulating the dates (years) in order to do a simple average. I'm inexperienced with pandas and wondering if there is a more elegant way than exporting to excel and changing the year! The data is in the form..

```
Date    
1899-01-01 00:00:00 100994.0
1899-02-01 00:00:00 100932.0
1899-03-01 00:00:00 100978.0
1899-11-01 00:00:00 100274.0
1899-12-01 00:00:00 100737.0
1900-01-01  100655.0
1900-02-01  100633.0 
1900-03-01  100512.0
1900-11-01  101212.0
1900-12-01  100430.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem.  Since you are averaging over five months this makes resampling more tricky.  You should be able to overcome this by logical indexing and building a new dataframe.  I assume your index is a datetime value.

```
index = pd.date_range('1899 9 1', '1902, 3, 1', freq='1M')
data = np.random.randint(0, 100, (index.size, 5))
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data=data, columns=list('ABCDE'))

# find rows that meet your criteria and average
idx1 = (df.index.year==1899) & (df.index.month >10)
idx2 = (df.index.year==1900) & (df.index.month < 4)

winterAve = df.loc[idx1 | idx2, :].mean(axis=0)
```

Just to visually check that the indexing/slicing is doing what we need....

```
>>>df.loc[idx1 | idx2, :]
Out[200]: 
             A   B   C   D   E
1899-11-30  48  91  87  29  47
1899-12-31  63   5   0  35  22
1900-01-31  37   8  89  86  38
1900-02-28   7  35  56  63  46
1900-03-31  72  34  96  94  35
```

You should be able to put this in a for loop to iterate over multiple years, etc.

Comment: That almost works! But as the dates in the output are the final days of the month its returning NaN as the value, as all my values are set at the beginning of the month. I'm not sure where this is being set...do you know of a way to adjust this?

Comment: a-ha! its solved by setting freq = '1MS' rather than '1M'. cheers

Comment: Good catch.  Glad it worked out.  Feel free to make this the accepted answer if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

Group data by month using pd.Grouper

```
g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M"))  # DataFrameGroupBy (grouped by Month)
```

For each group, calculate the average of only 'A' column

```
monthly_averages = g.aggregate({"A":np.mean})
```

Comment: OP wants to average data over multiple months, not just data within a single month.